# Can I change system files from custom kickstart .iso?

Tags: centos, scripting, proxy, kickstart

I have set up a Kickstart .iso installation of CentOS 7 and it installs nicely (.iso is compiled with ks.cfg file inside).

What I haven't figured out yet is if I could edit system files from within the iso installation to be able to create the file /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh with proxy configurations in it and also later be able to pass some yum commands so it updates by itself (this I read about in this forum but without the proxy setup yum can't do anything).

I have tried simply passing (as if I typed them in a terminal) the commands in the %post section of the ks.cfg file but it did nothing so I probably don't know very well how it works.

Can this be done or should I automate an ansible to do it?

I tried the following %post section:

```
%post
touch /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
echo 'Proxy info' >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
yum install whatever
%end
```

But I don't think I can throw commands at it like that because I'm technically inside the installation media and not the system itself.

Comment: You can run arbitrary commands in your `%post` script, so that should work fine. Perhaps you could update your question to show us your kickstart file (or at least the `%post` section)?

Comment: Updated with what I tried @larsks

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

I used this kickstart configuration:

```
text
url --url=http://mirror.facebook.net/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/

keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
lang en-US.UTF-8
network --bootproto=dhcp --ipv6=auto --activate
firewall --enabled --service=ssh
timezone US/Eastern --isUtc
selinux --enforcing
bootloader --location=mbr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart
reboot --eject

rootpw --plaintext secret

%packages
@Core
%end

%post
echo 'Proxy info' >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
%end
```

Tested it like this:

```
$ virt-install --name centos8-stream -r 4096 \
  --disk pool=default,size=10 \
  --os-variant centos8 \
  --location http://mirror.facebook.net/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ \
  -w network=default \
  --graphics=none \
  --console pty,target_type=serial \
  --initrd-inject ks.cfg \
  --extra-args='inst.ks=file:/ks.cfg console=ttyS0,115200n8'
```

When the system came up, the file was there as expected:

```
CentOS Stream 8
Kernel 4.18.0-373.el8.x86_64 on an x86_64

localhost login: root
Password:
Last login: Thu Apr 14 22:46:23 on ttyS0
-bash: Proxy: command not found
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
Proxy info
```

If you're seeing different behavior, post an example that reproduces it and I would be happy to take a closer look.